# liferay - how to render one portlet in another portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7, liferay-theme

New to Liferay.

Not sure if it's the right approach, but..

I have a page that renders a portlet. And in this portlet I need to render another portlet conditionally (based on a flag stored in the database).

I can retrieve this flag from the database in my portlet but how to render another portlet in the jsp view file is what I'm trying to understand.

So far I've found a liferay tag called `portlet:renderURL` that might achieve this, but the documentation and other articles I've read are super unclear as to what this tag is supposed to do and how it's supposed to do it? Am I in the wrong direction here?

Comment: An old guide from old liferay version , but I think still valid as starting point: https://liferay.dev/fr/ask/questions/development/runtime-portlet-from-jsp--1

Comment: seems like `liferay-portlet:runtime` is the best solution to achieve this.

Comment: @DanieleBaggio hey,`liferay-portlet:runtime` not working for me.. but portlet I'm trying to embed is `instanceable=true`. Should it be false for it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniele mentioned in a comment (but only by linking to an external article), you're rather looking for the `<liferay-portlet:runtime>` tag.

You mention "renderURL", which only results in a URL that would render *the whole page* including the portlet. I understand that you're looking at the content of just a single portlet to be rendered.

That tag should give you enough starting point to go for it: If you don't need to configure it with preferences, it's quite simple to use.

Not answering your question, but relating to the solution that you've chosen: Combining different portlets this way (interdependent) is not quite an ideal way of packaging code. Personally, I'd prefer to rather use common display routines rather than making one concrete portlet dependent on another concrete portlet.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What do you mean by "common display routines"? Are you talking about layout change? I can create a new layout for my usecase. But is there a way I can set the layout of the page dynamically based on the flag value I have in the db?

Comment: You can set a request attribute mvcPath with the path to the jsp you want to render. (From memory, check details, I'm currently on my phone with no access to more)